# Where is shapes.gates.ee.IEC referred to in the pgfmanual?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

I'm trying to create my own circuit elements for use with the `circuits.ee.IEC` TiKZ library, using some methods described (in other contexts) in the pgf manual (page 314, chapter 29.4.9). The first thing that happens in that chapter, is that the manual introduces a library called `shapes.gates.ee.IEC`, and suggests I import it like this:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.ee.IEC}
```

However, when I try to compile that, my XeLaTeX states that

```
>! I can't find file `tikzlibraryshapes.gates.code.tex'.  
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex   
\catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...  
l.7 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.ee.IEC}
```

and compilation fails. I can import `shapes` without problems, but if I add anything more from the name it fails again (I've tried `shapes.gates`, `shapes.gates.ee` and `shapes.gates.ee.IEC` without success). And when using `shapes` the shape I'm trying to use (`generic circle IEC`) isn't defined.

How do I get this working?

Comment: With last cvs version downloaded from [Paul Gaborit's repository](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html) this library is `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}`. `shapes.gates.ee.IEC` is a `pgflibrary` not a `tikzlibrary`.

Comment: With CTAN version, try with `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.iEC}`, I think you found an errata. You can look at [`TikZ` libraries list in CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the PGF Manual hasn't kept up with the rest of the package.

I suggest you try:

```
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
```

though without a full MWE I can't really check this out for you.

Comment: I already have that library loaded, on the line before, so unfortunately this won't help me.

Comment: @TomasLycken The TikZ library `circuits.ee.IEC` loads the pgf library `shapes.gates.ee.IEC`... So, what do you lack?

Comment: May I add a MWE in your answer?

Comment: Odd - I had all of these things spread over a few packages I've created, but when I copied them into a new .tex file to create an MWE and started to strip away things, it started working. I can add stuff again without messing it up. Apparently, I made a small mistake somewhere that I've corrected, but I can't figure out what it was...

Comment: @PaulGaborit : Please feel free to edit as much as you like. As an alternative, if you want to make your own answer, I'd be perfectly happy for Tomas to untick this one and tick yours.

Comment: My proposition of MWE was just an example from pgfmanual... But, it seems that it is no longer necessary as Thomas Lycken has corrected its code!